# KeychainItemWrapper linking error

Tags: ios, keychain

I just tried to use the KeychainItemWrapper provided by Apple, but I'm getting a linking error each time:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KeychainItemWrapper", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in DataModel.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've included the Security framework and checked why Apple included in the Xcode project, but I can't seem to find what else is going wrong.

```
_keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"com.website.project" accessGroup:nil];
[_keychain setObject:_username forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
[_keychain setObject:_password forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

I also added "com.website.project" to my Keychain Access Groups.

Comment: +1 you made me realize I forgot to add security framework ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Be sure the KeychainItemWrapper is in the "Compile Sources" list.

Comment: Aha, that works, thanks, shouldn't it be added automaticly when I import it in any class?

Comment: You have to tick the check mark next to the name of your target when you import files (I know, annoying).